# Is there a PostgreSQL function/keyword that can write to a file from within queries?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-trigger, dml

I remember back when I used to use MySQL, MySQL had a function that let you write to a system file anything you wanted. In fact, this is one of the many ways backdoor shells were uploaded to servers.

Anyway, what I want to do is create an AFTER INSERT trigger in a PostgreSQL table that will write some of the row's information to a file/pipe, with another process listening on the other endpoint.

I want this to behave like a message queue, but without using a broker.

Is there such an SQL function (standard or custom) that can let me achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: You want `copy`:  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html.

Comment: PostgreSQL does have a publish/subscribe option. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createsubscription.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [Postgres can be extended](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/server-programming.html) in a variety of programming languages with C, Python, Perl, and TCL available out of the box. From there you can do whatever you like. You might take some hints from [various replication systems](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Replication,_Clustering,_and_Connection_Pooling), in particular [Slony](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slony) is trigger-based.